# When two movieviewcontroller view's show on screen one disappears

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using Xcode's SplitView template.  I have placed a MovieViewController's view on the side bar during landscape mode.

I have other UIView's popping up over the DetailView (next to the side bar).  When another MovieViewController's view loads onto the screen the first one on the side bar disappears?

Anyone know why this is the car?

Comment: Is the first player actually disappearing or just not playing? You can only have one movie playing at once.

Comment: @James P if you answer the question I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.

[MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html)